# Sumerian: Why would 'gi(r)' in 'Ki-en-gi(r)' not simply mean 'reed'?

Tags: sumerian

The sign 'gi' obviously depicts a plant and its foremost meaning is 'reed' (Labat - Manual d'Epigraphie Akkadienne, 6th). The land is/was largely a reed-swamp. Without a name I would probably call it 'the reed land' or perhaps (referring to the chief or the people being masters of working with reed) something like 'land of the masters/lord(s) of the reed'. But I have not yet come accross such an interpretation. Hayes - A Manual of Sumerian Grammar and texts, 3rd, 2019 p66-67) for example lists some proposed etymologies that, to me, seem very far fetched. So, what is wrong with 'reed'?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but _gi_ "reed" doesn't have an R auslaut, does it?

Comment: I am from Basra, south Iraq. We still use some Sumerian words in our local Arabic dialect despite claims that the Sumerian language has disappeared. The word 'dingir' refers to a long pointed post... like that found in public squares or in the Ship as a mast or in carriage to hook the animals. This is not very different from 'reeds'. I was of the opinion that this referred to the single creator of the world as 'dingir' refers to the God too.

Answer (score 2):

There are several signs that are read GI and they have different figures to contrast them. It seems that gir15 is the Sumerian word for saying "Sumerian".
Eme-gir15 = Sumerian language, also written eme-gi-ra, or eme-gi7
Dumu-gir15 = Sumerian man, also written dumu-gi7, or dumu-gi7-ra
gir15 is sometimes replaced by the variants gi7-ra or gi-ra.
The word gir15 has nothing to do with gi "reed".

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Arnaud Fournet's answer:

Sumerian seems to have had a phonological process much like modern French, where most consonants aren't pronounced at the end of words. This means that *gi* "reed" and *gi* "Sumerian" may have been pronounced the same, based on Akkadian transcriptions in lexical lists.

But this changes when endings are added, like the genitive *-ak*. To my understanding, *gi* "reed" had no "hidden" final consonant (auslaut), so its genitive would be *gia*, while *gi* "Sumerian" had one, so its genitive would be *gi**r**a*. This is why the word is sometimes transcribed as *gi(r)*. (And the final *-k* of the ending is then also not pronounced, unless you add another ending after it, etc.)

Auslauts aside, though, according to the PSD the word for "Sumerian" was actually ***ŋ**ir*; the difference between *ŋ* and *g* is concealed by the Akkadian transcriptions, since Akkadian lacked `/ŋ/`. And as Fournet says, *ŋir* is written with the sign GIR₁₅ aka GI₇, while *gi* is written with the sign GI. This doesn't rule out the possibility that *ŋir* is historically derived from *gi*, but it implies that the Sumerians didn't think of it that way.

Comment: Agreed ! Sumerian seems to have plenty of secret consonants, which explains why a number of signs have variable readings like Cv(C).

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the difference between  respectively  "GIR₁₅ aka GI₇, while *gi* is written with the sign GI" (following @Draconis, above), additional complications arise when considering Sux.  *sag̃-gíg* and Akk.  *šumeru* (following Wikipedia: Sumer): "The first is the pictographic character for "head" [viz.  *sag̃*] the second the character for "night", and for "black" when pronounced *gíg*" -- caption under an image of an inscribed bust of Gudea.

Wiktionary distinguishes  (GE₆, Mi) in Akk. *mūšum*, *mušītum*, Sumerian *g̃i* "night" and Akk. *ṣalmum*, Sux. *giggi* "black" -- thanks to the good work of @Sartma. Note that *g̃* in EPSD and Wiktionary corresponds to *ŋ* in EPSD2 (The Pennsylvania Sumerian Dictionary Project).

Although *saŋ-gíg*, literally "head" + "black", sounds like a racial epithet, my impression from the frequent depiction of bald heads in Sumerian iconography begs to differ (note also the recent attempt at *night* to be derived from *naked*, Pooth 2015 *apud* Wiktionary: PIE **nókʷts*).

Anyway, the point to be made here is that *ŋir*, *ŋi* and *gíggi* are obviously colexified in some way, but the /m/ of akk. *šumeru* is difficult to justify as a sound change, and this does a priori not benefit an analysis of *gi* "reed", not the least because there is nearly a thousand years of difference between Gudea c. 2150 BC, the Early Dynastic Period c. 3350 – c. 2500 BC, and a period of proto-writing c. 4000 – c. 2500 BC. As for possible loanwords in Sumerian, cf. Jagersma 2010: 4, an early layer of borrowed nouns has a suffix -a, yet "An even older layer of endingless forms has been proposed, but remains unproven (Civil 2007; Sommerfeld 2006)."

Incidently, Egypt goes by a couple of names, *km.t* "the black land", *mḥ.t* "the Nile Delta" (or north), *ḥwt-kꜣ-ptḥ* "Egypt; Memphis; the temple of Ptah in Memphis", *tꜣ.wj* "the two lands" and a couple more. In this case, darkness is often attributed to wet, fertile soil. This might be close enough to to reeds or marshes, conceptually; not that e.g. *gꜣš* "reed, rush" (c. 19th century BC) would bear any resemblence to the above.

You can find *-gir* in words that mean farmer, but its not clear if this proves anything.

> So, what is wrong with 'reed'?

I don't believe that's the right question to begin with. First you must understand, why *gi* "noble" (Wikipedia), "Sumerian" (@Draconis) vel sim. should be prefered, by whom, since when, to be able to point out contradictions and gaps in the argument which you are trying to fill -- like so: *Noble* and *Sumerian* could easily come from semantic drift after the Ethnonym was already established. A comparable case is *frank and free*, which seems to be from the name of the Franks applied to a social class in medieval laws. The trivial answer is, of course, not *that* because *this*.